# MS Access: How to find the number of days between consecutive dates (same column) regarding one ID?

Tags: datediff

Using MS Access, I'm trying to find a formula or a function that returns the number of days between consecutive records. i.e.  how many days each sum has worked.
and if it was the last date in the group, I want the formula to return the number of days till the current system date.

image for the desired output

[image: image for the desired output]

Comment: What technology you want the solution in?

Comment: Commerce & Investment
I'm building a database using MS Access 2016

Answer (score 0):

Mr Ken Sheridan from Microsoft Community helped me with this amazing query code, and it worked.

```
Nz(DMin("TransactionDate", "Transactions","Investor = " & [Investor] & " And TransactionDate > #" & Format([TransactionDate],"yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"),Date()) - [TransactionDate]
```